# R and Radian with VScode C stack size too small

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, stack

When I run R (version 4.2.3) from the console using Windows 11 my C stack size (using Cstack_info() function) is 63737856 .

When I run R on the same machine, using the same R version (4.2.3) but using radian in VScode my C stack size is 1914470, or about 30 times smaller than when using the R console.

This small C stack size when using radian/VScode causes me to hit the dreaded "C stack usage XXX is too close to the limit" error when running some large shiny apps. Just barely (meaning my C stack size at 1914470 is almost big enough, but not quite, so I don't think there's some big recursion issue blowing up my stack, and app also works fine on the console instance of R).

I am a novice when it comes to Python/C++ (and largely VScode), and I can't figure out how to have a bigger C stack size when I fire up radian in VScode with Windows. (in Linux, apparently there is the Ulimit -s option to modify stack size used by R). Any suggestions on increasing my C stack size to around the value it has when using R from the console?

My searches on stackoverflow tend to refer to solutions when running Linux...

Comment: This issue is probably not related to VS Code, just radian. Looks like it is discussed here: https://github.com/randy3k/radian/issues/214

Comment: Thank you @andycraig. Yes appears to be a radian issue, not a VS Code issue as per the link. Unfortunately, there is apparently no realistic solution currently for increasing stack size when using radian from it's pitiful small allocation at startup. It's possible the issue is restricted to shiny apps running R 4.2.X, though that may just reflect some increased stack requirements for R 4.2.X over R 4.1.X I don't know.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction at least.